# Grouping dictionary data from a list and storing in another dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am currently working on a big data set where the data is stored into list with dictionaries (format shown below)

```
List = [{ID001: Report-1, ID002: Report-1, ID003: Report-1}, {ID001: Report-2, ID005: Report-5}…..]
```

I am trying to group and print a list with one dictionary that contains all ID’s from all dictionaries in the above list with related values (in this case report-1, report-2…)

```
result_List = {ID001: [Report-1, Report-2, Report-5], ID002: [Report-3, Report-6, Report-23]}
```

I thought of using for loop, but once the first dictionary is done looping through all the other dictionaries in list, it has to store unique ID’s in the result_List.

The code itself contains lot of loops, which I believe too complex for a list of 200 dictionaries with data.

I am looking for something with Pandas or Numpy with relatively less complex. Can anyone suggest the best way to do this kind of data crunch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way it can be done.

```
data =  [{ID001: Report-1, ID002: Report-1, ID003: Report-1}, {ID001: Report-2, ID005: Report-5}…..]
d = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
res = d.to_dict("list")
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove null values too:

```
data =  [{'ID001': 'Report-1', 'ID002': 'Report-1', 'ID003': 'Report-1'}, {'ID001': 'Report-2', 'ID005': 'Report-5'}]
d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
result={k:[i for i in v if type(i)==str] for k, v in d.items()}
print(result)
```